# Web audio: Output to center speaker only

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm playing around with the web audio context and trying to understand how the splitter node works.

I've managed to split an oscillator node and connect it to output only to the left/right channels, but I'm having some hard time outputting it to the "center" channel alone...

given the following code

```js
    const ac = new AudioContext();
    const splitter = ac.createChannelSplitter(6);
    const oscilator = ac.createOscillator();
    const merger = ac.createChannelMerger(6);
    oscilator.frequency.value = 440;
    
    const gainNode = ac.createGain();

    // connect oscilator to splitter channel
    oscilator.connect(splitter);

    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.5, ac.currentTime);
    splitter.connect(gainNode, 0);
    gainNode.connect(merger, 0, 2);
    merger.connect(ac.destination);

    oscilator.start(0);
    oscilator.stop(1);
```

I expect the oscillator tune to be outputted only in my "center" speaker, but I hear the sound from both.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on how your output device is configured.  If you only have stereo output speakers, then the center channel will be heard in both speakers.

For these kinds of things, I find it best to use a 6-channel `OfflineAudioContext` and then to look at the channels of output.  Don't know if this is still maintained, but I find [Canopy](https://hoch.github.io/canopy/) to be very useful for this kind of exploration.